# In Java, am I safe to assume that `==` will work to compare objects of type `Class<?>`?

Tags: java, class, equals

I understand that if an object does not explicitly override `equals`, it uses the base `Object.equals()` instead, which is effectively no different from the `==` operator.

`Class<?>` does not explicitly override `equals`, so my next question is, am I guaranteed that two `Class<T>` of the same will compare `==` with equals? Or, could one instance of a `Class<T>` that I declare be a different object reference than another one with the same type argument `T`?

In other words, is there any possibility with a conforming Java environment that the following code would output anything other than `"true"`?

```
public class ClassA
{
    private static final String STRING = "Hello World";
    public final Class<?> theClass = STRING.getClass();
    public final Class<?> theClass2 = "Goodbye World".getClass();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        System.out.println(Boolean.toString(a.theClass == a.theClass2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `.equals()` is not "effectively no different from `==`", those two things do _completely_ different things.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I said `Object.equals` is effectively no different than `==`

Comment: Which is incorrect, it is _nothing_ like `==` except for the part where both yield a boolean value. One is a custom method that can do whatever the programmer likes, the other is an operator that tests for identity.

Comment: The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true). ` Javadoc for `java.lang.Object`

Comment: Think of "==" as “does this object-reference point to the same location in memory as this other object-reference?”. The content and type of the objects is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, in that sense. Then yes, the implementation in Object is a fallback to `==`, but that's probably the worst way to think about how to test equalities. Treat `==` as _identity_ (e.g. as Basil points out: are these two things _not_ two things, but _one_ thing, and we're just pointing to the same memory location in two different ways) and `.equals` as _equality_ (e.g. "can I consider these the same thing based on some of their properties, even though they separate things"). And if you don't implement your own `equals` the answer will be `==`'s "no, because they're two different things".

Comment: Duplicate was incorrect.  This question is not asking about two classes with the same name appearing to be unequal (because they came from different classloaders).  The question is asking whether the JVM creates one and only one instance of java.lang.Class for each class that is loaded, in which case it would be safe to compare their references.  (My own opinion:  I just use `equals` so I don’t have to worry about it.)

Comment: This is a trivial example that will always print `true`, because the two strings will have the same class loader and thus will be instances of the same String.class. However, in deployed applications that use containers etc, multiple class loaders can be present in which case what should be "the same" class, may not be `==`.

Comment: The short answer is no. No two classes loaded by different classloaders can possibly be equal under `==`.

Comment: Added a better dup.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty safe.

From the [Java Virtual Machine Specification § 5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> well-behaved class loader should maintain three properties:
>
> Given the same name, a good class loader should always return the same Class object.
>
> …

This means that while it is not guaranteed, you may assume that the classloader you're using adheres to that statement.

This of course assumes that each class is loaded by a single classloader. The model used by the JVM is that classloaders may *delegate* the loading of a class to another classloader. So while I cannot find exactly whether it's prohibited to load the same class by different classloaders, I cannot imagine, under normal circumstances, how the class instance on the left-hand side of the `==` operator would be different than the instance on the right-hand side.

Comment: Examples of the same class loaded by dfferent classloaders abound. Two copies of the same webapp. Two webapps that each loaded the same JDBC driver.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, but how would you access two `Class` instances loaded by those classloaders at the same time?

Comment: You would obtain two instances of them from different APIs and call `instance.getClass()`.